# Relative paths not working under current Apache settings

Tags: html, apache

I'm getting this strange behavior using relative paths on a directory with *DirectoryIndex*.

This is the directory structure:

```
/project/index.html
/project/css/main.css
/project/scripts/site.js
```

When I load the index.html file using this path:

```
www.mydomain.com/project/index.html
```

Everything loads just fine.

When I load like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/project/
```

First, the ending slash gets removed, second, the browser is looking for the CSS/JS at:

```
www.mydomain.com/css/main.css
www.mydomain.com/scripts/site.js
```

Which is obviously wrong.

I'm referencing the assets like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles/main.css" />
```

I also tried adding "./" and same results.

Why is this happening? I'm still new to Apache configs so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I don't want to use *../css/main.css* to reference the assets because if somebody lands on the *index.html* file directly, then the assets won't load.

I'm pretty sure it's a dumb problem I'm over thinking.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be having `/project/styles/main.css` instead of just `styles/main.css`.

Comment: I could use that path, yes. The problem is my dev environment and prod environment don't have the exact same depth, so I need it to be relative to the _index.html_ file so that it works in both. You think the behavior I'm seeing is normal then?

Comment: I would not call it normal.